# Incorrect output by goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

I am watching a lecture in which author build a status app using go routines which is behaving weirdly after sometime.

Here's the code:

```
func main() {
    links := []string{
        "http://google.com",
        "http://facebook.com",
        "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "http://amazon.com",
        "http://golang.org",
    }

    c := make(chan string)

    for _, link := range links {
        go checkLink(link, c)
    }

    for l := range c {
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            checkLink(l, c)
        }()
    }
}

func checkLink(link string, c chan string) {
    _, err := http.Get(link)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(link, "might be down!")
        c <- link
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(link, "is up!")
    c <- link
}
```

The output I get is:

> http://stackoverflow.com is up!
>
> http://google.com is up!
>
> http://facebook.com is up!
>
> http://golang.org is up!
>
> http://amazon.com is up!
>
> http://amazon.com is up!
>
> http://amazon.com is up!
>
> http://amazon.com is up!
>
> http://amazon.com is up!
>
> http://amazon.com is up!

I don't understand why the "amazon.com" keeps on repeating here?? Why is this happening after all the 5 links has been printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the closure capturing of the loop variable `l`. Since the goroutine is started inside a loop, all goroutines created by the loop share the same memory address for `l`. By the time the sleep is over and the goroutine is executed, the value of `l` has changed due to the loop iterating over the remaining links. Consequently, all goroutines end up checking the last link in the `links` slice, which is **"http://amazon.com"**.
To fix this, you need to pass the loop variable `l` as an argument to the anonymous function inside the goroutine. Here's an updated version of the code:

```
for l := range c {
    go func(link string) {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        checkLink(link, c)
    }(l)
}
```

By passing `l` as an argument to the anonymous function, each goroutine will have its own copy of `l`, preserving the correct value for each iteration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, NubDev! Many or most of your 23 answers in the last two weeks appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.